# Image Height Exceeding Wrap Content Android

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview, cardview

I am using xamarin android to make a android app in which i am using cardview with recycler view.

**Problem**

Image height is exceeding the wrap content of the text.

**What is Want**

I want the image size to be the size covered by text.

**What I Have Tried:**

I have tried setting image as a background of the linearlayout but it  sets the height of the layout itself much greater than shown in images below.
i have tried setting this in framelayout but it gives same result as below

**Details about the images**

numbers are provided with the instance of the card view in

1: image the image source height is increasing the view height

2: this image is setted perfectly because the original image height resolution is low and the image is stretched to view

3: again image height resolution is high so the view is extended by image

4,5 cardview without image

**My Code:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent">



        <ImageView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:scaleType="fitXY"
             android:id="@+id/cardImage"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/templateLayout"
            >

            <TextView
                android:text="Title:"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:id="@+id/listTitle"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="Start Time:"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:id="@+id/listSTime"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="End Time:"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:id="@+id/listFTime"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="Description:"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:id="@+id/listDescription"/>


        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Images:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Add the following fields to ImageView

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change the imageView attributes to `android:scaleType="centreCrop"` and change the height  to `wrap content`. you are matching it to `parent` in you case,its the card view. Whereas, textview is in a linearlayout.

Orelse you can move `ImageView` to same linearLayout of the `textView`

Comment: oh yes you are right the textview is in linearlayout
but if i add scaletype centre crop that simply crops the view of image 
and the image is partially visible and if i add imageview in linearlayout then the texts will be rendered after the view of image is finished
if i add it as background of linearlayout it will also exceed the textview size and it doesnt support scaletype too

Comment: or you can just leave the `imageView` to as it is. make the width and height to wrapcontent

Comment: if i do `wrap_content` to image view and add a less resolution image the rest of the view will be empty and if i do this after putting the image in linearlayout then again other views will start after imageview is ended